# Merging HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page which is loaded first. This page has some jQuery which fades in an image and text, after a set time this is faded out. The page then changes to the next page.

The problem is, when it changes page, the background becomes white because it's loading that new page. I'm using the exact same background images btw.

So I guess either solve one of the following as they're all that I can think of.

**Option 1)** Have a script which loads the background image some how before the body is loaded. Only issue with this is, I'm setting the background in the body tag. `<body onload="preLoader()" background="images/blue.png">`

**Option 2)** Somehow merge page one into page two which I would think is too difficult.

Just for additional information, here's the jQuery from the first page:

```
        var delay = 6500;
        $('#pre_title').hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#loader_logo').hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#pre_title').delay(500).fadeOut(2000);
        $('#loader_logo').delay(500).fadeOut(2000);
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "ls.php"; }, delay );
```

and here's the jQuery which fades in the HTML on the second page.

```
    function preLoader() {
        $("html").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the entire html tag? Can't you just load some main div in your body? (Which not include the bg image)

Comment: Not hard to load content using ajax. Really not clear what you are trying to do on a higher level

Comment: @ItayB, that's exactly what I was going to suggest. Just make sure all Javascript/CSS that's required for the next page is already included in the original page.

Comment: How resource heavy are the pages? If they are both fairly light I don't see a problem with merging them. Let's say both pages are stored in separate divs abstracting out things like header, footer and background. Just have a click event that grabs the currently active div and hides it with whatever animation while unhiding the other one with whatever animation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bare-bones, Vanilla JS proof-of-concept implementation using iframes to get you started.

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            body {background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);font-size:4em;}
        </style>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        this is page 0...this is page 0...this is page 0...<br />
        this is page 0...this is page 0...this is page 0...<br />
        this is page 0...this is page 0...this is page 0...<br />
        this is page 0...this is page 0...this is page 0...<br />
        this is page 0...this is page 0...this is page 0...<br />
    </body>

    </html>
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .2);font-size:4em;}
    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    this is page 1...this is page 1...this is page 1...<br />
    this is page 1...this is page 1...this is page 1...<br />
    this is page 1...this is page 1...this is page 1...<br />
    this is page 1...this is page 1...this is page 1...<br />
    this is page 1...this is page 1...this is page 1...<br />
</body>

</html>
```

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            body {background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);font-size:4em;}
        </style>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        this is page 2...this is page 2...this is page 2...<br />
        this is page 2...this is page 2...this is page 2...<br />
        this is page 2...this is page 2...this is page 2...<br />
        this is page 2...this is page 2...this is page 2...<br />
        this is page 2...this is page 2...this is page 2...<br />
    </body>

    </html>
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image:url('http://stmed.net/sites/default/files/stone-wallpapers-28059-3653690.jpg');
            position:absolute;top:0,left:0;;height:100%;width:100%;
        }
        #pFrame0, #pFrame1 {position:absolute;top:20px,left:20px;opacity:1;height:100%;width:100%;}
        #pFrame1 {opacity:0;}
        form {position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;z-index:3;}
    </style>
    <script>
        var dir = 'file:///home/richard/Documents/code/';
        var pageList = [
            'page0.html', 'page1.html', 'page2.html'
        ];

        function get(eId) {return document.getElementById(eId);};

        var nextPageIdx=0;
        function run() {
            nextPageIdx++
            nextPageIdx = (nextPageIdx == pageList.length)?0:nextPageIdx;
            loadPage(pageList[nextPageIdx]);
        };

        function loadPage(uri) {
            var current = (1 == 1*get('pFrame0').style.opacity)?'pFrame0':'pFrame1';
            var next = (1 == 1*get('pFrame0').style.opacity)?'pFrame1':'pFrame0';
            setTimeout("swapPages('" + uri + "','" + current + "','" + next + "'), crossFade('" + current + "', '" + next + "')");
        };

        function swapPages(uri, current, next) {
            get(current).src = get(next).src;
            get(current).style.opacity = 1;
            setTimeout("get('" + next + "').style.opacity = 0;", 50);
            setTimeout("get('" + next + "').src = '" + uri + "';", 100);
        };

        function crossFade(current, next, msecs) {
            if ('undefined' == typeof msecs) msecs = 5000;
            var delta = 100/msecs;
            get(current).style.opacity = 1;
            get(next).style.opacity = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < msecs/100; i++) {
                setTimeout("get('" + current + "').style.opacity = (1*get('" + current + "').style.opacity) - " + delta, i*msecs/100);
                setTimeout("get('" + next + "').style.opacity = (1*get('" + next + "').style.opacity) + " + delta, i*msecs/100);
            }
            return msecs;
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="pFrame0" src="file:///home/richard/Documents/code/page0.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="pFrame1" src="file:///home/richard/Documents/code/page1.html"></iframe>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="load next page" onclick="run();" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```